# Using Plotly.js to draw two bar charts and two scatter plots and share the same x-axis

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

we want to use one graph to show both bar charts for each year for a measure but also a scatter (or line) for the same year. By default this seems to create the x-axis labels twice.

Also it seems to also interpolate between 2016 and 2017 by putting 2016.5 (which obviously make no sense).

Note: we're using angular-plotly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [simple example](https://codepen.io/zax-s/pen/ZEYRZMX) of what seems to me you are describing. As you can see there is only one x-axis label.

[Angular-plotly](https://github.com/plotly/angular-plotly.js/blob/master/README.md) has almost exactly the same example too - just the measure is different, but nothing prevents you from having `x` and `y` the same in both elements of `data`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'plotly-example',
    template: '<plotly-plot [data]="graph.data" [layout]="graph.layout"></plotly-plot>',
})
export class PlotlyExampleComponent {
    public graph = {
        data: [
            { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 6, 3], type: 'scatter', mode: 'lines+points', marker: {color: 'red'} },
            { x: [1, 2, 3], y: [2, 5, 3], type: 'bar' },
        ],
        layout: {width: 320, height: 240, title: 'A Fancy Plot'}
    };
}
```

[image: fancy plot from github documentation]

If that is not what you are looking for, please provide your code.

*EDIT:*

Answering to the comment, to avoid fractional ticks, you can limit the axis ticks to the array of x values by providing the layout as following (I updated the codepen too):

```
var trace1 = {
  x: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005],
  y: [1.5, 1, 1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
  type: 'scatter'
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005],
  y: [1.5, 1, 1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9],
  type: 'bar'
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

var layout = {
                xaxis:{
                  type: 'dates',
                  tickangle: 0,
                  tickvals: trace1.x
                }            
              };

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

Comment: Hi and thanks. It'll take me a while (few weeks tops) to try this out as we've moved a bit on the project and busy doing other things. But I'll surely reply and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: About the second part of my question, is it possible to NOT have interpolation between values of the axis? Even in your example, if I zoom in I get these orrible .5 values.

Comment: You can use the layout parameter and it's `tickvals` property to limit the ticks to any values (in fact you can have dates, months, cities or whatever the meaning of the tick in the axis is) and they will not interpolate. I updated the answer. Good luck!